# Double PopUP Onclick IE8

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
<script>

    function Results()
    {
        document.report_form.action = "index.php?p=report_view";
        document.report_form.target = "_blank";    
        document.report_form.submit();             
        return true;
    }

    function CSV()
    {
        document.report_form.action = "csv.php";
        document.report_form.target = "_blank";    
        document.report_form.submit();             
        return true;
    }

</script>

<form name='report_form' method='post'>

    <input type='submit' name='view_table'  value='Display' onclick="return Results();">
    <input type='submit' name='view_csv'    value='Export CSV'        onclick="return CSV();">

</form>
```

When using Firefox or Chrome, it doesn't trigger a double popup, when using IE8 , users click once on the button and either 2 windows popup or 2 download requests appear.

I couldn't find a solution to this, can you please show me where I am wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I suspect these code `document.report_form.target = "_blank";    
document.report_form.submit();`, on click should open a new window with report.

Comment: You are submitting the form twice: just remove the `document.report_form.submit();` lines.

Comment: you are right shadow wizard, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try return false; instead of return true;

Comment: Unless you explain and give more details, this should be a comment - answer is expected to contain more details.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Normally I'd agree that more detail is better, but in this case I think it's pretty obvious that this answer is saying that the two places in the _short_ question code that have `return true;` should be changed to `return false;`. (Given that sample code I can't think of any other interpretation.) Not that it wouldn't be nice to know _why_ this would fix things, but it is enough information to get the code working...

Comment: @nnn fair enough, answer might solve the question but adding details saying *why* it solve would also make it a good answer not just ordinary trivial answer. Someone suggested to totally change this answer hour ago to make it what it should have been from the first place but I voted to reject it - the author of the answer is not worthy of the points awarded as result of somebody else work.